# How do I use ngx.location.capture() with proxy_pass in a kong plugin?

Tags: nginx, lua, openid-connect, kong

I'm currently writing a Kong plugin. When I receive a request with a token, I want to request an external service to validate the token. I read that you can use location_capture and proxy_pass to do external HTTP requests.

I'm not sure exactly how to do this. I've put

`location = /reqbin {
    proxy_pass https://requestb.in/yn3pykyn;
}`

in the nginx_kong.lua file. Is that where it's supposed to go?

In my plugin code, I have:

```
res = ngx.location.capture("/reqbin", {method=ngx.HTTP_POST, args=args})
```

But when I use curl to request Kong, the request goes straight to the upstream_url, and I can tell that my requestbin was not hit. What am I doing wrong?

edit: Also, the current res has:

status: 500

body: nil

headers: Content-Type: text/plain, Server: kong/0.10.3

truncated: true

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice library that helps you to do this requests: https://github.com/pintsized/lua-resty-http I've been using it for the same purposes and it works great.